# How can I track usage statistics for specific Windows applications using ElectronJS?

Tags: windows, electron, event-tracking

I'm working on an Electron application and I need assistance in implementing a feature that tracks the usage of specific Windows applications, such as Chrome and MS Excel. I want to be able to monitor when these applications are opened and closed, and potentially gather usage statistics or perform certain actions based on the application usage.

Specifically, I'm looking for guidance on how to achieve the following within my Electron application:

1. Detect when specific Windows applications, such as Chrome and MS Excel, are opened by the user.
2. Track the duration for which these applications remain open.
3. Capture events when these applications are closed or switched to another application.
4. Potentially gather additional usage data, such as the number of times the application was opened in a session or the total time spent using the application.

I'm using Electron as the framework for my application, and my target platform is Windows. I would appreciate any advice, guidance, or code examples on how to implement this functionality effectively using Electron's APIs or any relevant third-party libraries.

I have tried using these libraries

1. ```
   "chokidar": "^3.5.3",
   ```
2. ```
   "electron-squirrel-startup": "^1.0.0",
   ```
3. ```
   "ps-list": "^8.1.1",
   ```
4. ```
   "systeminformation": "^5.17.12",
   ```

Thank you in advance for your help!